# What are analogous words to "occidental" and "oriental" for southern and northern?

Tags: synonyms, geography, direction

***Definitions***

Occidental: "1: relating to the countries of the West"

Oriental:  "1. of, relating to, or characteristic of the Orient, or East; Eastern."

So, occidental is effectively a word that is a synonym to western, and oriental is a synonym to eastern.

Do similar words to these exist for northern and southern?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what you have against "northern" and "southern"?

Comment: Nothing, but I was curious.

Answer (score 3):

We have the words **"septentrional"** and **"meridional"**.  "Boreal" and "austral" wouldn't be good fits as they relate to the north of the Northern Hemisphere and the southern parts of the Southern Hemisphere. Then again, "septentrional" and "meridional" can refer to the northern or southern part of any country or region respectively, irrespective of the hemisphere  where they are located. Surely both words are dated and we would rather use "northern" and "southern".

> - [**septentrional**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/septentrional) - northern (rare).
> - [**meridional**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/meridional) - located in the south; southern.

Example sentences from [**EOD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/meridional)

- "the meridional leg of the journey"

Other examples from  the web:

- "in **meridional** regions of the Qinghai-Xizang Plateau (China), from low latitudes to high latitudes, there is a phenomenon of oscillation of atmospheric low frequency wave with 30-40 day period."
- "Prenatal exposure to organochlorines and heavy metals in the Arctic largely exceeds that encountered in **meridional** regions of the province of Quebec."
- "By far the most disturbing event of the **meridional** leg of the journey was..."

The Latin word septentrional, as mentioned by Sven Yargs, would be the perfect opposite for meridional except that it is seldom used in English. It's commonly used in Romance Languages, though.

Addendum: In BrE "[meridional in temperament](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meridional)" relates to "Southern Europe" or Mediterranean, especially the South of France.

Comment: But southern France is "meridional" -- not exactly the Southern Hemisphere.

Comment: https://www.synonyms.com/antonyms/boreal

Comment: From your definition of "meridional":  An inhabitant of a southern region, especially the south of France.

Comment: @HotLicks     Can you wait until I have finished ?

Comment: The examples you give are using definition 1 of "meridional", a definition which in no way satisfies the OP's request.

Comment: Various websites also cite _austral_ as an option for "southern" and "[_septentrional_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septentrional) for "northern."

Comment: @HotLicks   Meridional Africa and Meridional Australia are not located in the Northern Hemisphere.  The Brits use the word "meridional" for southern France or an inhabitant of southern France.  But that's another story.

Comment: @Centaurus - So California would be regarded as the "oriental US"?

Comment: @HotLicks No, occidental US.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - So New Jersey is oriental?

Comment: @HotLicks Archaically, yes. In modern parlance, of course not. In modern parlance there are no north-south counterparts to _occidental_ and _oriental_ at all because the broad division of the world into ‘western’ and ‘eastern’ countries – which is not based on geography, but culture – has no north-south equivalent (and also leaves out a huge part of the world). There is no such thing as ‘northern civilisation’ and ’southern civilisation’, and also no Latinate word for either.

Answer (score 2):

The regions associated to the cardinal directions are called *boreal* for the north, *occidental* for the west, *austral* for the south, and *oriental* for the east.

Comment: There is the problem that "boreal", in particular, as acquired a connotation of "cold", and would normally be regarded by some people to apply to only the northern half of the northern hemisphere.